# serial communication Blender Game Engine to arduino?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, communication, blender

I need help from communicating serial data from blender game engine to *arduino*.

I'm making keyboard input from blender and trying to communicate to *arduino*, but it's not working.

**This is blender code**

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM6", 9600)
x=ser.write(1)   
print(x)
ser.close()
```

**Logic**

Key "a" --> Python script

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAUfI.png]

**and this is the arduino code i trying to communicate from blender.**

```
int led = 2;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if ( Serial.available())
    {
        char ch = Serial.read();
        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, when *Blender Game Engine* (BGE) running, and I press Key 'a' blender communicate with arduino and LED turn on.

Am I doing wrong?

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

in your blender python code, you're sending an integer:

```
x=ser.write(1)
```

whereas in your arduino code you're checking for an ASCII digit between `'0'` and `'9'`, i.e. numbers between 48 and 57

```
if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
```

either try to change your python code to `ser.write('1')` or change your arduino code to `ch >= 0 && ch <= 9`, and it should work.

Also, before binding your code as a script inside blender, you should first test your python script outside of blender. simply by running using the commandline: `python script.py`, in the directory where the script is.